# "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed" when reading from database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, pdf, resultset

This is the error log shown when i executed the code

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:743)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6301)
>   at reportpdf.ReportPDF.main(ReportPDF.java:84)

And here is my code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

public class ReportPDF {
    private static Font headerFontBold = new                                 Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED,14,Font.BOLD);
    private static Font headerFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED,12);
    private static Font titleFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED,12,Font.BOLD);
    private static LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    private static String output = ""+localDate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document document = new Document();
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("Inventory Report "+output+".pdf"));
        document.open();

        Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph("Company Name", headerFontBold);
        para1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
        para1.setSpacingAfter(2);
        document.add(para1);

        Paragraph para2 = new Paragraph("Address", headerFont);
        para2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
        para2.setSpacingAfter(2);
        document.add(para2);

        Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph("Inventory Report", headerFont);
        para3.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
        para3.setSpacingAfter(20);
        document.add(para3);

        Paragraph para4 = new Paragraph("Inventory Report as of: "+  new Date(), titleFont);
        para4.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
        para4.setSpacingAfter(2);
        document.add(para4);

        Paragraph para5 = new Paragraph("Generated by: ", titleFont);
        para5.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
        para5.setSpacingAfter(2);
        document.add(para5);

        Paragraph para6 = new Paragraph("Generated for date/s: ", titleFont);
        para6.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
        para6.setSpacingAfter(20);
        document.add(para6);

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
            Connection  con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pdfreport?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "root");
            Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select id, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, birthday, age from pdfreport.registration;");

            PdfPTable recordTable = new PdfPTable(6);
            PdfPCell recordCell;

            while (rs.next()) {                
                String id = rs.getString("id");
                recordCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(id));
                recordTable.addCell(recordCell);

                String firstName=rs.getString("firstName");
                recordCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(firstName));
                recordTable.addCell(recordCell);

                String lastName=rs.getString("lastName");
                recordCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(lastName));
                recordTable.addCell(recordCell);

                String emailAddress=rs.getString("emailAddress");
                recordCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(emailAddress));
                recordTable.addCell(recordCell);

                String birthday=rs.getString("birthday");
                recordCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(birthday));
                recordTable.addCell(recordCell);

                String age=rs.getString("age");
                recordCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(age));
                recordTable.addCell(recordCell);

                document.add(recordTable);                       
                rs.close();
                st.close(); 
                con.close();
                document.close();                    
            }            
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        document.close();
    } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}    
}
```

What I know or I think the error is in retrieving the database entries but i don't really know what exactly. i've been trying solutions and just can't seem to get it in my head. thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You close the result set **inside** the while loop, so the next call to `rs.next()` fails with the error you get:

```
while(rs.next())
{
    ....

    rs.close(); 
    st.close(); 
    con.close();
    document.close();        ...
}
```

So in the second iteration you try to read from a *closed* result set.

Move those `close()` calls outside the `while` loop:

```
while(rs.next())
{
    ....
}
rs.close(); 
st.close(); 
con.close();
document.close();        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your document etc. too early.

```
while (rs.next())
{                
    // do some stuff

    document.add(recordTable);                       
    rs.close();
    st.close(); 
    con.close();
    document.close();
}
```

Once the document is closed (i.e. on the second iteration of your loop), you cannot add anything more to it. If you move the close statements to after the while loop, you should be okay:

```
while (rs.next())
{                
    // do some stuff

    document.add(recordTable);                       
}
rs.close();
st.close(); 
con.close();
document.close();
```